# Which module supporting Google Charts allows for data being specified via a REST call?

Tags: views, charts

I'm looking for a contributed module for Drupal 7 which can be used for creating a chart, and which satisfies all of these criteria:

1. Use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) (the newest 'interactive' ones) as the charting engine (renderer).
2. Must provide an integration with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.
3. The data to be charted are specified via a [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) call, e.g. by using some [json](/questions/tagged/json) query string.

Anybody any suggestion for any such module (or combination of modules)?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Please be sure to try Google **before** posting questions here, this isn't your own personal Drupal search engine! We're trying to build a repository of _high quality questions and answers_, and broad questions like this that show no research effort don't help us do that. Searching Google for your exact question title yields 3 modules that will help, as the first 3 results.

Comment: Apart from Clive's answer from "some time ago", and while waiting for this question to eventually be reopened, consider lookiing at https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985 ... it answers already 2 of your 3 questions. With some extra homework it should be possible to also answer question 3 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google chart tools](https://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) for that. It works really well with views.

> Display live data on your site using Google Chart Tools Google Chart
>   Tools module provides a simple API to Build custom interactive SVG
>   charts. The module contain an example module which demonstrate how
>   this module can be use.